# Combining two tables based on closest text match

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

First of all, thanks for clicking. Second of all, bear with me, this is a bit awkward to explain.

Alright. So I have two tables in an Excel with similar data as follows:

```
Organization            | Code
------------------------+---------
University of Chicago   | 123123
University of Maryland  | 030393
Therapy Incorporated    | 2324
Martians United         | 022222
League of Superheroes   | 94949


Organization                            | ID
----------------------------------------+---------
University of Chicago Medical Center    | 1
University of California Dental         | 9
Therapy Inc.                            | 3
League of Artificial Men                | 4
League of Superheroes                   | 5
```

I've transferred this to Access in the hopes of using queries to combine the data using INNER JOIN and LEFT 10 or so, but now I'm getting this:

```
Organization            | Organization                          | ID    | Code
------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------+-----------
University of Chicago   | University of Chicago Medical Center  | 1     | 123123
University of Chicago   | University of California Dental       | 9     | 123123
University of Maryland  | University of Chicago Medical Center  | 1     | 030393
University of Maryland  | University of California Dental       | 9     | 030393
Therapy Incorporated    | Therapy Inc.                          | 3     | 2324
League of Superheroes   | League of Superheroes                 | 5     | 94949
League of Superheroes   | League of Artificial Men              | 4     | 94949
```

A few issues with this. For one, the University of Maryland doesn't have a match, but instead picks a match of the Univeristy of Chiago or CA. Single records are listed are listed multiple times.

I also have no way of seeing records that have no match (Martians United) beyond creating a new query and then finding a way to combine the two results.

My closest Access query so far:

```
SELECT 
    [Organizations Not In PARTY].[Organization Name], 
    [Orgs In PARTY Table].Name, 
    [Organizations Not In PARTY].Count, 
    [Orgs In PARTY Table].ID
FROM 
    [Organizations Not In PARTY] 
    INNER JOIN 
    [Orgs In PARTY Table] 
    ON LEFT ([Organizations Not In PARTY].[Organization Name],15) LIKE LEFT ([Orgs In PARTY Table].[Name],15);
```

This results in repeats and matches such as the Univ. of Chicago and Maryland examples above.

Beyond that, I've tried the following so far:

- Moving query results to a new table to prevent repeats: Access didn't like this, it kept trying to move results regardless of repeats. I believe the issue is it attempts to move all results at the end.
- INNER JOIN with less or more characters: still results in repeats.

I'm getting a wee bit desperate (that would be why I'm here :/) and am probably going to start going through all ~3,000 records manually. I'd be happy to buy someone coffee for some guidance.

Comment: Joins based on fuzzy text matching are challenging.  It can be reasonable when the text variations all conform to one consistent pattern ... but that is not what you're dealing with.  For this one, I would create a mapping table to store the proper *Organization* matches.  Then join your base tables to the mapping table.